# Can event.origin be manipulated to be a regex match?

Tags: security, cross-domain, postmessage

I would think this is a non-issue, but thought I'd get some assurance.

I have a cross-frame messaging script using postMessage. The very first thing it does upon receiving a message is check its origin:

```
if (indexOf(whiteList, event.origin) === -1){
    return false;
}
```

Where `whiteList` is an array of acceptable origins and `indexOf` is a very simple shim to `array.indexOf`:

```
indexOf = (function() {
    if(typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === "function") {
        return function(haystack, needle){
            return haystack.indexOf(needle);
        };
    }
    return function(haystack, needle) {
        var i, index = -1, l = haystack.length;
        for(i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            if(haystack[i] === needle) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    };
})();
```

I'm wondering if there's any way that if the event.origin were a regex "string", they could force a true condition. I would think not in my shim: the `===` always returns false comparing a string to /[a-zA-z]/g or some such, as far as I know, and I was unable to trick native `Array.indexOf()` function with regex in my testing (always returns -1).

But I don't know much about security and hacking. Community, your thoughts?